# Update MongoDb with random number WITHIN a range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update (`AvgCostCalc`) a document property in MongoDb collection for all documents using the following:

```
db.ProviderSearchFacilities.find({
    Random: {$exists : false}
}).forEach(function(ProviderSearchFacilities) {
    db.ProviderSearchFacilities.update(
        {_id: ProviderSearchFacilities._id}, 
        {$set : {Random: Math.random()}}
    )
})
```

My collection is like: ProviderSearchFacilities.Providers[0].AvgCostCalc

This query doesn't seem to work and also I need the `Random` number to be within 150 and 200. Please advise where I'm wrong.

 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a work around for this. Used the formula given [here](https://github.com/Rafase282/My-FreeCodeCamp-Code/wiki/Lesson-Generate-Random-Whole-Numbers-within-a-Range) to work in parallel with `Random` to get the number within a range.